# Dynamic adding input field using p:commandButton?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I can add dynamic input field in my form:

```
                <h:form>
                    <h:dataTable id="tblFields" value="#{templateOptionBean.fields}"
                        var="field">
                        <h:column>
                            <h:inputText value="#{field.value}" />
                        </h:column>

                        <h:column>
                            <h:commandButton value="Remove">
                                <f:ajax
                                    listener="#{templateOptionBean.onButtonRemoveFieldClick(field)}"
                                    immediate="true" render="@form" />
                            </h:commandButton>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>

                    <h:commandButton value="Add">
                        <f:ajax listener="#{templateOptionBean.onButtonAddFieldClick}"
                            execute="@form" render="tblFields" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
```

my backend looks like that:

```
    @ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TemplateOptions implements Serializable
{
    private List<Field> m_lFields;

    public TemplateOptions()
    {
        m_lFields = new ArrayList();

        m_lFields.add(new Field());
    }

    public void setFields(List<Field> p_lFields)
    {
        m_lFields = p_lFields;
    }

    public List<Field> getFields()
    {
        return m_lFields;
    }

    public void onButtonRemoveFieldClick(final Field p_oField)
    {
        m_lFields.remove(p_oField);
    }

    public void onButtonAddFieldClick(AjaxBehaviorEvent p_oEvent)
    {
        m_lFields.add(new Field());
    }
}
```

However, when I change the button in my form to `p:commandButton` then my logic does not work anymore.

However, i want to use these types of Buttons. Therefore, how can I use this type of button?

I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: You change to a `<p:commandButton/>` and still keep the `<f:ajax/>`? That's not going to work, they're not meant for each other XD.

Comment: @kolossus is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to use an other component library like Primefaces then the components can be different the the others. So if you take a look in the primefaces showcase at commandbutton you see how you can easly make a Ajax call at your bean (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf) So in your case changes two things your bean and your page. 
Lets start with the page:

```
<p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" update="tblFields" id="ajax"  
         actionListener="#{templateOptionBean.onButtonAddFieldClick}" />
```

With primefaces you don't need the f:ajax you can directly use it in your command button.

In your bean change the onButtonAddFieldClick method. Primefaces is firing a javax.faces.event.ActionEvent (See showcase) So change it like this:

```
public void onButtonAddFieldClick(ActionEvent  p_oEvent)
{
    m_lFields.add(new Field());
}
```

And voilla it works with the p:commandButton